# How to show a 'grep' result with the complete path or file name

Tags: linux, bash, grep

How can I get the complete file path when I use `grep`?

I use commands like

```
cat *.log | grep somethingtosearch
```

I need to show the result with the complete file path from where the matched result were taken out.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming you have two log-files in:

- C:/temp/my.log
- C:/temp/alsoMy.log

'cd' to C: and use:

```
grep -r somethingtosearch temp/*.log
```

It will give you a list like:

```
temp/my.log:somethingtosearch
temp/alsoMy.log:somethingtosearch1
temp/alsoMy.log:somethingtosearch2
```

Comment: How can I get the line number of the searched content?

Comment: @Özzesh add -n for reporting linenumbers

Comment: But the question is tagged with Linux and Bash. This seems to be for Windows. What was this run under? Which environment?

Comment: Ubuntu line count (from `man grep`) use: `-c, --count
              Suppress normal output; instead print a count of matching lines for each input file.  With the -v, --invert-match option (see below), count non-matching lines.`

Answer (score 12):

I think the real solution is:

```
cat *.log | grep -H somethingtosearch
```

Comment: If you pipe the file contents to `grep` instead of passing file names as arguments, `grep` cannot know file names and prints "(standard input)" instead.

Comment: this is the only solution that seems correct based on my understanding of the question. -H will show the path to the file that was searched. brilliant

Comment: For -H to show the full path you must *specify the full path* as the search directory rather than a relative path (I had some trouble until I realized this).

Answer (score 10):

Command:

```
grep -rl --include="*.js" "searchString" ${PWD}
```

Returned output:

```
/root/test/bas.js
```

Comment: it is printing one directory two times, one with absolute path and one with relative path, can I ignore relative path somehow?

Comment: -rl was enough for me, thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you want to see the full paths, I would recommend to `cd` to the top directory (of your drive if using Windows)

```
cd C:\
grep -r somethingtosearch C:\Users\Ozzesh\temp
```

Or on Linux:

```
cd /
grep -r somethingtosearch ~/temp
```

If you really resist on your file name filtering (*.log) *and* you want *recursive* (files are not all in the same directory), combining `find` and `grep` is the most flexible way:

```
cd /
find ~/temp -iname '*.log' -type f -exec grep somethingtosearch '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 4):

It is similar to [BVB Media's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47420001/8863043).

```
grep -rnw 'blablabla' `pwd`
```

It works fine on my [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) Bash.

Comment: it is printing one directory two times, one with absolute path and one with relative path, can I ignore relative path somehow?

Comment: @WasimA. It only prints absolute path, not with relative path on my bash. do you have different environment? I'm using ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Answer (score 1):

For me

```
grep -b "searchsomething" *.log
```

worked as I wanted

Comment: It's not about what you want, it's about what OP wants.

Comment: @a20: But it ***is*** the OP (self answer).

Comment: Classic comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

This works when searching files in all directories.

```
sudo ls -R | grep -i something_bla_bla
```

The output shows all files and directories which include "something_bla_bla". The directories with path, but not the files.

Then use *[locate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locate_(Unix))* on the wanted file.

Comment: What can said about parsing the output of [`ls`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ls)?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print full paths is to replace the relative start path with the absolute path:

```
grep -r --include="*.sh" "pattern" ${PWD}
```

Comment: it is printing one directory two times, one with absolute path and one with relative path, can I ignore relative path somehow?

Answer (score -4):

Use:

```
grep somethingtosearch *.log
```

and the filenames will be printed out along with the matches.